# There is no Swift -like syntax of Java ‘SuppressWarnings("unchecked")’

Tags: swift

code:

```
note.userInfo as! NSDictionary
```

warning:

> Cast form '[NSObject : AnyObject]?' to unrelated type 'NSDictionary' always fails

Comment: What are you asking?

Comment: I  want Elimination this Warning

Comment: Then you need to fix your code. In this case, "always fails" mean the cast will always return nil. That's probably not what you're after.

Comment: func keyBoardWillShow(note:NSNotification){let userInfo  = note.userInfo as! NSDictionary
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To say

```
let userInfo = note.userInfo as! NSDictionary
```

is silly, as this is *already* an NSDictionary. But it could be `nil`, so it is an Optional wrapping a dictionary. So you need to unwrap it. If you are certain there is a `userInfo`, then say

```
let userInfo = note.userInfo!
```

If you are not sure, then unwrap safely.